# iOS OAuth2 client secret parameter not available in Google credentials

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-api

I've created a new project and generated a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID but there doesn't appear to be any client secret available within credentials. The documentation for OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps:Step 5 states that this parameter needs to be provided.

Heres a request:

```
▿ https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
  ▿ url : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
      - _url : https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
  - cachePolicy : 0
  - timeoutInterval : 30.0
  - mainDocumentURL : nil
  - networkServiceType : __C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
  - allowsCellularAccess : true
  ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
    - some : "POST"
  ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
    ▿ some : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "Content-Type"
        - value : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
  ▿ httpBody : Optional<Data>
    ▿ some : 372 bytes
      - count : 372
      ▿ pointer : 0x00007fce7b5186f0
        - pointerValue : 140524808931056
  - httpBodyStream : nil
  - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
  - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

The request body data contains the exact same parameter values for client_id, redirect_uri and code_verifier used to successfully obtain a valid authorisation code.

Any request with no client_secret or using an empty string returns 400.
Any request using anything but an empty string returns 401, invalid_client error.

Here's a link to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#ios

Here's a link to the project:
https://github.com/PJCSpencer/SwiftOAuth2Client

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the format of the request body?

Comment: It's an NSData object containing the uft8 encoded string.

Comment: The string is a URLComponents query.

Answer (score 0):

I was using code_challenge to exchange the authenticate_code for an access token, when I should have been using initial code_verifier. The Spotify authorisation guide on code flow helped me spot the bug.